# check if html radiobutton is checked with cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have been searching all over google for a solution but i cant find anything. I want to check if the HTML radio button is checked with cshtml. This is what i have right now:

```
<input type="radio" name=question id="V1A1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name=question id="V1A2" /> No
string V1A1 = Request.Form["V1A1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery:

```
$('#V1A1').prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery:

```
$('#V1A1').is(':checked')
```